# Netbeans Platform Layout

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have designed a little application using netbeans platform and now i want to change the orientation of the basic layout provided by netbeans platform. I have a window displaying like this shown below
[image]

I want the abouve screen to be displayed like below on the startup. I have resized to suit my needs but i want that to happen by itself.

[image]

After intense googling i found that i need to create a `layer.xml` in one of the module and add the following code to it.

`<folder name="Windows2">
        <file name="WindowManager.wswmgr" url="WindowManager.wswmgr"/>
    </folder>`

My `WindowManager.wswmgr` file looks like this

```
<windowmanager version="2.1">
<main-window> 
    <joined-properties centered-horizontally="true" centered-vertically="true"
                       width="630" height="400" />
    <separated-properties centered-horizontally="true" relative-y="0.1"
                       relative-width="0.6" relative-height="0.08" />
</main-window>
<editor-area state="joined">
    <constraints>
        <path orientation="horizontal" number="60" weight="0.5" />
        <path orientation="vertical" number="40" weight="0.7" /> 
        <path orientation="horizontal" number="40" weight="0.5" /> 
    </constraints>
    <relative-bounds x="33" y="24" width="42" height="44"/>
</editor-area>
<screen width="1024" height="800" />
<active-mode name="explorer" />
<maximized-mode name="" />
<toolbar configuration="Standard" preferred-icon-size="24" />
```

What do i have to do now? Am I missing some obvious things ??

--EDIT--

layer.xml

```
<filesystem>
<folder name="Actions">
    <folder name="Window">
        <file name="org-choose-transaction-ChooseTransactionTopComponent.instance_hidden"/>
        <file name="org-choose-transaction-EnterAmountTopComponent.instance">
            <attr name="instanceCreate" methodvalue="org.openide.windows.TopComponent.openAction"/>
            <attr name="preferredID" stringvalue="ChooseTransactionTopComponent"/>
        </file>
        <file name="org-prowze-maketransaction-TransactionTopComponent.instance">
            <attr name="instanceCreate" methodvalue="org.openide.windows.TopComponent.openAction"/>
            <attr name="preferredID" stringvalue="transactionTopComponent"/>
        </file>
        <file name="org-prowze-maketransaction-transactionTopComponent.instance_hidden"/>
    </folder>
</folder>
<folder name="Toolbars_hidden"/>

<folder name="Windows2">
    <folder name="Modes">
        <file name="explorer.wsmode" url="explorer.wsmode"/>
        <folder name="explorer"/>
    </folder>   
    <file name="WindowManager.wswmgr" url="WindowManager.wswmgr"/>
</folder>
```

explorer.wsmode

```
<mode version="2.4">
<module name="org.netbeans.core.ui/1" spec="1.2" />
<name unique="explorer"  />
<kind type="view" />
<state type="joined"  />
<constraints>
    <path orientation="horizontal" number="20" weight="0.3"/>
    <path orientation="vertical" number="20" weight="0.5"/>
</constraints>
<bounds x="192" y="228" width="614" height="520" />
<frame state="0"/>
<active-tc  id="CustomerViewerTopComponent" />
<empty-behavior permanent="true"/></mode>
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but: I think if you make your TopComponent have a minimum size (implement `getMinimumSize()` to take your graphics into account) and activate the "Respect mininum size" in your application "Branding" properties then this should be happening automatically.

Comment: Respect Minimum size has effect only when resizing.. I have tried that actually!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WindowManager.wswmgr` file defines the main window's attributes. The other piece that you need to define is the explorer mode (assuming that the CustomerViewer Window is in the explorer mode).

Defining and registering a mode is similar to how you've defined and registered the `WindowManager.wswmgr` file. The pragmatic way¹ of determining what the xml should look like is to run the application, move the divider to the desired position, close the application, and open the following file from the Files explorer`<Your_NB_Application>/build/testuserdir/config/Windows2Local/Modes/explorer.wsmode`.

Copy the contents from the `explorer.wsmode` into a file named `explorer.wsmode` which you can create in the module's root package (`com.example.mymodule`). Now you need to register this file in your layer file:

```
<folder name="Windows2"> 
    <file name="WindowManager.wswmgr" url="WindowManager.wswmgr"/> 
    <folder name="Modes">
        <file name="explorer.wsmode" url="explorer.wsmode"/>
        <folder name="explorer"/>
    </folder>        
</folder>
```

*Be sure to run "Clean and Build All" on your application before running it again.*

¹The formal way for determining the structure is to use the dtd located at http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/mode-properties2_4.dtd

Comment: The path in my system is not `<Your_NB_Application>/build/testuserdir/Windows2Local/Modes/explorer.wsmode.` it is `<Your_NB_Application>/build/testuserdir/config/Windows2Local/Modes/explorer.wsmode.`

Comment: I have done the steps and still it doesn work. I have posted my layer.xml and explorer.wsmode file as edit

Comment: Actually the overridden explored.wsmode seems to be doing nothing or its not even recognised...

Comment: From your edit, it looks like you didn't move the divider before you copied the contents of `explorer.wsmode`. It's hard to believe that the `horizontal` `weight` property could be exactly `0.3` after moving the divider.

Comment: Also, be sure to run "Clean and Build All" on your application.

Comment: actually i did!!! i moved the divider and copied!! Also if i change the 0.3 to 0.5 and nothing changed!

Comment: When I moved the divider the only value changed was `<bounds x="192" y="228" width="614" height="520" />`

Comment: Hmmm, something else must be wrong. This technique works on my machine (NB 7.1). You could try starting a new app to test this technique and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: thanks for your help.. I will consider starting a bounty on this!

Comment: I am trying to use this advice, but am at a loss as to where I should save the wsmode file. I tried placing it in the same directory as the source for that module. That didn't do anything.

Comment: You can put the `wsmode` file in any of your source packages - I recommend putting it in the module's root package. Then you need to let the platform know about this file by adding the entry in your layer file (this is the XML that I've posted in the answer and the `url` attribute is relative to your module's root package). If your module doesn't have a layer file then you'll need to create one by right clicking on your module > New > Other > Module Development > XML Layer.